# Use of BOM with transitive dependency in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-jetpack-compose

I am learning to use [BOM](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup#using-the-bom) in my project

```
def composeBom = platform "androidx.compose:compose-bom:$compose_bom"
implementation composeBom
androidTestImplementation composeBom
```

I saw in the [gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sub:using-platform-to-control-transitive-deps) doc.  Use of `platform` is used in transitive version. So what the connection of `platform` with `BOM`?  Any guidance will be great..

> **Note:** I don't have too much knowledge of transitive dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **`platform`** is a special software component which can be used to control transitive dependency versions.

From gradle docs:

> A component may have two different kinds of dependencies:
>
> - **direct dependencies** are directly required by the component. A direct dependency is also referred to as a first level dependency. For example, if your project source code requires Guava, Guava should be declared as direct dependency.
> - **transitive dependencies** are dependencies that your component needs, but only because another dependency needs them.

The `BOM` file has:

- a pom packaging type
- a `dependencyManagement` section that lists the dependencies of a project with the **recommended** versions.

The Compose BOM file contains:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>androidx.compose.animation</groupId>
            <artifactId>animation</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>androidx.compose.material</groupId>
            <artifactId>material</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--  others -->
</dependencyManagement>
```

Gradle treats all entries in the `<dependencyManagement>` block of a BOM similar to Gradle’s **dependency constraints.** This means that any version defined in the `<dependencyManagement>` block can impact the dependency resolution result.

It means that the BOM itself has links to the **stable versions of the different Compose libraries**, in such a way that they work well together. When using the BOM in your app, you don't need to add any version to the Compose library dependencies themselves.

To use

```
dependencies {
    // Import the Compose BOM
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.12.00')

    // Import other Compose libraries without version numbers
    implementation 'androidx.compose.foundation:foundation'
}
```